# Can I prevent "def" to be overriden with "val"?

Tags: scala

I have a trait the defines an abstract method without parameters. I want to prevent implementors from overriding this with `val`, so the method is called every time its value is needed. For eg.

```
sealed trait Downloader extends Loader {
  def username: String
  def password: String
  def nonceProvider: NonceProvider

  def request: Request

  def download = {
    val client = new Client
    client execute request
  }

}
```

This is a trait used for downloading certain resources. Now someone could write the following bad implementation:

```
case class DownloaderWithServiceDefinition(
  override val username: String,
  override val password: String,
  override val nonceProvider: NonceProvider
  serviceDefinition: ServiceDefinition) extends Downloader {

  override val request = ServiceDefinitionRequest(serviceDefinition, username, password, nonceProvider.generateNonce())

}
```

In this implementation, `request` is assigned a value during construction instead of behaving like a method, so consecutive requests will have the same nonce value which is obviously not intended. Can i prevent this?

Comment: IMO, preventing clients from overriding `request` with a `val` is a moot point - they'd still be able to override it with a method that always returns the same instance. A `val` is simply a degenerate `def`.

Comment: So do you suggest I leave it as it is, and document that a new nonce has to be generated every time?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do. Actually, stating that the request should be generated every time it's called implies that a new nonce should be generated as well.

Comment: @SzakállasDávid You could also change the signature to `def request: () => Request`—this can still be implemented with a constant value, but it's less convenient, and the intent is a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not want that as a general language feature. The assumption is that a trait requires *SOME* valid implementation of `request` of the right type, and codes that requirement. But a trait can make no assumptions/demands on the implementation details of this requirement.

As such, an implementer has the liberty to use a def, a val, a var or even a lazy val as it sees fit, with greater knowledge than the trait has. And if a correct implementation is what concerns you, then the burden of avoiding bugs is indeed in the implementation itself.

You can change your definition to `def request(): Request` or `def request: () => Request` to make intent clearer and document the contract you need (actual java/scala doc helps).

It might be even that the request itself, if only used as a ***way*** to obtain the nonce, should not be in the trait at all as it is an implementation detail. I would gather than a `Downloader` would probably not have a single `Request` at all, but make many as needed, so you might have a smell that you should structure your OO Design differently.